# Visual Studio - How to change project's Entities name?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to change entity name for my WPF project, Is that possible ? and how ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you call an "entity name"?

Comment: The current name from my entity is AlrakizaTouch, but I have changed the project name, So I want to change it.

Comment: I don't understand what "entity" mean to you? To me, this is a record, a row. Sounds like you talking about assembly name. Am I correct?